# Laravel 5.7 Problem in multiple authentication(This page isn’t working)

Tags: laravel-5.7, laravel-authentication

I just started in Laravel framework. I'm watching the tutorials on youtube "How to make a multiple authentication". Everything is working well, I can login for both users(user/staff),register new account but I realized that when the credentials is incorrect(either of the two users) it will give me an error

```
This page isn’t working 127.0.0.1 is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

NOTE: Got 2 model: 1) User 2) Staff

```
User Table:
email - xxxx@gmail.com
password - 123456
Staff Table:
email - xxxx@gmail.com
password - 123456
```

Scenario 1: When I input the correct credentials, it is correct

```
Login

Email:xxxx@gmail.com
Password:123456
```

But when the credentials is incorrect

Scenario 2: Incorrect credentials

```
Login

Email:xxxx@gmail.com
Password:12345
```

[image]

**StaffLoginController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Auth;
class StaffLoginController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:staff');
    }
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.staff.login');
        // return view('layouts.staff.app');
    }
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        // Validate the form
        $this->validate($request,[
            'email'     => "required|email",
            'password'  => 'required|min:6'
        ]);

        // Attempt to log

        if(Auth::guard('staff')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password],$request->remember))
        {
            // If successful, then redirect 
            return redirect()->intended(route('staff.index'));
        } 


        // If unsuccessful, then redirect to login
    }
}
```

**Handler**

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        // return parent::render($request, $exception);
        $guard =  array_get($exception->guards(),0);
        switch ($guard) {
            case 'staff':
                # code...
                $login = 'staff.login';
                break;

            default:
                # code...
                $login = 'login';
                break;
        }
        return redirect()->guest(route($login));
    }
```

**Web**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');


Route::prefix('staff')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/', 'StaffController@index')->name('staff.index');
    Route::get('/login','Auth\StaffLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('staff.login');
    Route::post('/login','Auth\StaffLoginController@login')->name('staff.login.submit');
});
```

Question: What is the cause of this error?

Comment: Try turning on debugging by "debug=true" in the .env file. It will show an error to share.